# Eclipse Plugin development :Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry

Tags: eclipse, plugins

**Trying to run eclipse plugin By right click on plugin project and run as eclipse  Application then getting following error.**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data
```

P:\Users\xvervik\workspace/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:P:/Users/xvervik/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

```
    This is a continuation of log file P:\Users\xvervik\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\Eclipse Application\1509351929492.bak_6.log
    Created Time: 2017-10-30 13:55:48.161

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqleditor 2 0 2017-10-30 13:55:48.170
    !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqleditor [236]
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="[3.11.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="3.11.2.v20170220-1911"
           org.eclipse.jface.text [411]`enter code here`
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.text; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.text; bundle-version="3.6.0.v20160503-1849"
                  org.eclipse.text [767]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

         !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 0 2017-10-30 13:55:48.576
    !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui [890]
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.12.0,4.0.0)"
        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.12.3.v20170119-0935"; singleton:="true"
           org.eclipse.ui.ide [783]
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.106.0,4.0.0)"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.108.1.v20160929-1045"; singleton:="true"
                  org.eclipse.ui [776]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                      -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.108.3.v20170216-1539"; singleton:="true"
                         org.eclipse.ui.workbench [798]
                           Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal
                             -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal; bundle-version="0.11.100.v20160506-0804"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                                org.eclipse.e4.core.commands [244]
                                  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                                    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                                       org.eclipse.e4.core.di [246]
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="[1.4.0,2.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                                           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="1.5.0.v20151127-1241"
                                              org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations [247]
                                                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                                  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log
                                    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log; bundle-version="2.0.100.v20160509-1032"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                                       org.eclipse.e4.core.services [249]
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
                                           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                                  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
                                    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts; bundle-version="1.5.1.v20170203-1100"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"; version="0.0.0"
                                       org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts [245]
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
                                           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                           Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands
                             -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands; bundle-version="0.11.100.v20160506-0804"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress,  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.tests"
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="[3.10.100,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                      -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="3.12.2.v20170113-2113"; singleton:="true"
                         org.eclipse.jface [409]
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.108.3.v20170216-1539"; singleton:="true"


    !ENTRY org.eclipse.wtp.xml.capabilities 2 0 2017-10-30 13:55:48.583
    !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.wtp.xml.capabilities [945]
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench
        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.108.3.v20170216-1539"; singleton:="true"
           org.eclipse.ui.workbench [798]
             Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal
               -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal; bundle-version="0.11.100.v20160506-0804"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands [244]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                      -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                         org.eclipse.e4.core.di [246]
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="[1.4.0,2.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                             -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="1.5.0.v20151127-1241"
                                org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations [247]
                                  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                    Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log
                      -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log; bundle-version="2.0.100.v20160509-1032"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                         org.eclipse.e4.core.services [249]
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
                             -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                    Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
                      -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts; bundle-version="1.5.1.v20170203-1100"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"; version="0.0.0"
                         org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts [245]
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
                             -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
             Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands
               -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands; bundle-version="0.11.100.v20160506-0804"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress,  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.tests"


    !ENTRY org.eclipse.compare.win32 2 0 2017-10-30 13:55:48.589
    !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.compare.win32 [96]
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.compare; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.compare; bundle-version="3.7.1.v20170103-1805"; singleton:="true"
           org.eclipse.compare [94]
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.108.1.v20160929-1045"; singleton:="true"
                  org.eclipse.ui [776]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                      -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.108.3.v20170216-1539"; singleton:="true"
                         org.eclipse.ui.workbench [798]
                           Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal
                             -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal; bundle-version="0.11.100.v20160506-0804"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                                org.eclipse.e4.core.commands [244]
                                  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="0.9.0"
                                    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                                       org.eclipse.e4.core.di [246]
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="[1.4.0,2.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                                           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations; bundle-version="1.5.0.v20151127-1241"
                                              org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations [247]
                                                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                                  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log
                                    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log; bundle-version="2.0.100.v20160509-1032"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.services"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
                                       org.eclipse.e4.core.services [249]
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
                                           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                                  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts
                                    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts; bundle-version="1.5.1.v20170203-1100"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts"; version="0.0.0"
                                       org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts [245]
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                                         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.core.di
                                           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.core.di; bundle-version="1.6.1.v20160712-0927"
                           Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands
                             -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.core.commands; bundle-version="0.11.100.v20160506-0804"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.core.commands"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,  org.eclipse.ui.workbench,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt,  org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress,  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.tests"
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="[3.10.100,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                      -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface; bundle-version="3.12.2.v20170113-2113"; singleton:="true"
                         org.eclipse.jface [409]
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="3.11.2.v20170220-1911"
                  org.eclipse.jface.text [411]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.text; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                      -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.text; bundle-version="3.6.0.v20160503-1849"
                         org.eclipse.text [767]
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


    !ENTRY org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core 2 0 2017-10-30 13:55:48.596
    !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core [434]
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.filebuffers; bundle-version="[3.4.0,4.0.0)"
        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.filebuffers; bundle-version="3.6.0.v20160503-1849"; singleton:="true"
           org.eclipse.core.filebuffers [105]
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.text; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.text; bundle-version="3.6.0.v20160503-1849"
                  org.eclipse.text [767]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


    !ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.debug 2 0 2017-10-30 13:55:48.603
    !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jdt.debug [384]
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.core; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.core; bundle-version="3.12.3.v20170228-1205"; singleton:="true"
           org.eclipse.jdt.core [382]
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.team.core; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.team.core; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20160418-1534"; singleton:="true"
                  org.eclipse.team.core [765]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.compare.core; bundle-version="[3.5.200,4.0.0)"
                      -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.compare.core; bundle-version="3.6.0.v20160418-1534"
                         org.eclipse.compare.core [95]
                           Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.text; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.text; bundle-version="3.6.0.v20160503-1849"
                  org.eclipse.text [767]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"


    !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 2 0 2017-10-30 13:55:48.610
    !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core [844]
      Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension.loader
        -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension.loader; bundle-version="1.0.2.v201610280128"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension"; version="0.0.0"
           org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension [2]
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
             Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.osgi; bundle-version="3.10.0"


    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-30 13:55:48.629
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.nativePackageExtractor, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

Comment: Eclipse Neon requires Java 8

Answer (score 1):

Some of the required plug-ins require **Java 8** (e. g. `filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"`), but you only have Java 7: `java.version=1.7.0_71`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me. But launching with different workspace it give
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$1
Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$1

Comment: This seems to be another problem not on startup, but on shutdown. You could ask a further question on Stack Overflow or in the [Eclipse Forum of the Marketplace Client (MPC) project](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=176).